# Need a matrix with counts of intersecting values

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
Fruit    Colour
Apple      Red
Apple      Green   
Cherry     Red
Lemon      Yellow 
Banana     Yellow
Blueberry  Purple
Grapes     Purple
Grapes     Green
```

And would like a matrix which looks like this:

```
           Apple    Cherry    Lemon    Banana    Blueberry    Grapes
Apple       0         1         0         0         0            1            
Cherry      1         0         0         0         0            0
Lemon       0         0         0         1         0            0
Banana      0         0         1         0         0            0
Blueberry   0         0         0         0         0            1         
Grapes      1         0         0         0         1            0
```

Corresponding to a the number of shared values between the rows in the colour column.

I've tried something like this:

```
df1 <- dcast(fruit_frame, Fruit~Colour)
```

Which gives me a dataframe with the colour as the columns and fruit as rows and number of occurrences of each colour but it isn't quite what I am looking for. Is there an easy way to do this in R or python?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: If it's python, it has to be with pandas. Is that what you're using (or open to)?

Comment: You may need `tcrossprod(table(fruit_frame))` in `R`

Comment: Please also complete the table and show your expected result.

Comment: @cs95 yup pandas is good

Comment: @akrun this is giving me a product of the values, rather than the number of shared occurrences?

Comment: OK, how does `u = pd.crosstab(df.Fruit, df.Colour); v = u.dot(u.T); np.fill_diagonal(v.values, 0); print(v)` work?

Comment: @epigeneticist - it gives the shared occurrences. The diagonal is the raw frequency count, or how often the value occurs in combination with itself.

Comment: @epigeneticist  Wouldn't Apple and Grapes share 'Green' ? (based on the input example)

Comment: @akrun yes you're right! edited

Comment: @epigeneticist In the first column also, there should be one more 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option in `R` would be

```
out <- tcrossprod(table(fruit_frame))
diag(out) <- 0
```